# Is this Informix SE?

Tags: informix, database

I have a group of files that have extensions of .dat & .idx.  They seem to be named in pairs.  These files were under a folder named deeds.dbs.  How do I access this data?  Sorry for the general question, but I know nothing about Informix at all.

Comment: where you successful in accessing the data?

Comment: your welcome.. you know, you can also use the dbschema utility to obtain a schema of all the tables in deeds.dbs if you need to know the layout and datatype of all the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; the names you give (directory 'deeds.dbs' and contents in pairs of files, xyz.dat and xyz.idx) are very characteristic of Informix SE.  The database would be called 'deeds'.  You can find the manuals for SE at the [IBM web site](http://www.ibm.com/software/data/informix/se/support/doc.html).

There was an earlier - much earlier, as in last updated in 1986 - product called Informix 3.30 (with no qualified name like Informix SE or Informix OnLine).  Informix would have used a file 'deeds.dbd' to contain the database dictionary for the 'deeds' database (hence the suffix) and would have used the C-ISAM files (such as file.dat, file.idx) in the same directory (usually) as the '.dbd' file.